# return request as response in fetchEvent

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, service-worker

Inside a service-worker I try do return the emitted request as response if the request has failed. It seems to be very simple but it doesn't work.

In fact, when I try to return it, it returns an empty object, even with  `.clone()`.

Here is the code:

```
fetch(event.request.clone())
      .catch((err) => {
        queue.addRequest(event.request)
        return new Response(JSON.stringify({ deferred: true, ...event.request }), {
          headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })
        })
      })
```

The response of it is always: `{ deferred: true }`. And nothing else.

Is it possible to do it ?

Comment: Can you show where are you calling this function ? What is event request ?

Comment: I call this in : `self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => { ... })`

Comment: Do you need to request the data twice ?

Comment: The request is not sent twice to the server. The service-worker is like a proxy. Here I just handle the request in the middle.

Comment: Show more context... what is queue, what is self ?

Comment: self is the serviceWorkerGlobalContext (not declared around this code, this is a keyword), and queue is a Workbox (Google library for service-worker) class. This will not help to answer. This is all about the request class: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the way to get the request body and return it in my case.

It is possible to get it using `.json()` that return a promise with the request body.

It look like this:

```
fetch(event.request.clone())
      .catch((err) => {
        queue.addRequest(event.request)
        return event.request.clone().json().then((requestBody) => {
          return new Response(JSON.stringify({ deferred: true, ...requestBody }), {
            headers: new Headers({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })
          })
        })
      })
```